# I will try to change the version code and version name for android app but it gives the following error

Tags: android, version

```
C:\Users\hp-\IdeaProjects\new\app\build.gradle
Error:(11, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'versionCode()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'new' may be using a version of Gradle  that does not contain the method.
<a href="open.wrapper.file">Open Gradle wrapper file</a></li>
<li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>
```

This was the  error  how to fix it?

I will change in build.gradle as follows

```
   defaultConfig {
    applicationId "  name.name"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1.1
    versionName "1.1"
     }
```

Comment: please post your `build.gradle` file code

Comment: defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ishu.ishu"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1.1
        versionName "1.1"
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant use a float number for  `versionCode`. you must use an integer number.
just  `versionCode` must be more than previous  `versionCode` like it:

1, 2, 3, 4, ...

Comment: in Android Studio manifest file no need. but in eclipse have to change it in manifest. excuse me for bad English